# Changing ISO 8601 date string to 24 hours from its current value

Tags: php, sql, date

I have an ISO 8601 string like so:

```
2016-09-26T20:38:15.793Z
```

Now, I want to push the date forward 24 hours, but in the "Y-m-d H:i:s" format. I experimented with the following:

```
//$date1 is ISO 8601 string
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($date1, '+24 hours'));
```

But unfortunately that's not working. Am I on the right track or completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: not working **HOW**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/DateTime) class. Make a new instance, add 24 hours to it and format it.

```
$dt = new DateTime('2016-09-26T20:38:15.793Z');
$dt->modify('+24 hours'); 
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

https://3v4l.org/CHmmm

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `strototime`, you have the arguments in the wrong order, and you'll need to either convert your string to a timestamp first, which would require another application of `strtotime`, or concatenate it with the `+24` modifier. It would need to be like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+24 hours', strtotime($date1)));
```

or like this:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("$date1+24 hours"));
```

(I would also recommend using the `DateTime` class instead, but just FYI.)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the sub method of the datetime class http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.sub.php